# HTTP Error 404 IIS 10

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

I created a new web site named employmentapplication and pointed it to c:/inetpub/wwwroot/employmentapplication
I set the bindings to employmentapplication
Set the .Net to 4.0 on the Application Pool.
Created the Application naming it the same and pointed it to the same folder.
Created the virtual directory naming it the same and pointed it to the same folder.
I published my web site from Visual Studio 2015 to the folder.
Started IE and typed http://employmentapplication and got the HTTP 404 error. There was nothing added to the log.

Comment: You need a server address: `http://127.0.0.1/employmentapplication` ?

Comment: In addition to what Alex K. said, you'll need to clear the "binding" entry from the site settings as well

Comment: Edit your host file and add a line in there as follows "127.0.0.1      employmentapplication". Save the host file. You should be able to open the site as you planned, http://employmentapplication.